# Редактор с разбиением окна на буферы как в vim или emacs

Tags: редактор-текста, vim, emacs, linux

Интересует вопрос - существуют ли редакторы, под Linux, в которых есть возможность разбить одно окно редактирования файла, на два, как это можно в vim или emacs, потому что очень часто полезно видеть перед собой одновременно два исходника.

И ещё хотел бы узнать, чтобы не создавать новый вопрос - чем emacs или vim лучше (особенно в наше время)? Все говорят, что они настраиваемы до неузнаваемости, но в чем выражаются эти настройки. Что можно полезного извлечь (для веб-мастера к примеру) из этих редакторов, чего нет в других?

P.S. Для себя я пока усвоил только разбиение окна на буферы.

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше думать о коде, чем о том, какой комбинацией клавиш скопировать текст в буфер, или почему написал кучу кода не глядя на экран, а оказывается не перешел в режим редактирования.  
Просто есть фанаты, которые будут говорить, что vim это адово круто и для избранных, но ведь есть, например, и фанаты поедания кактусов, которые будут говорить то же самое о поедании кактуса, но мы то знаем.

Comment: Меня в них привлекает отображение сразу двух файлов. Есть в других редакторах для linux такая же функция?

Comment: Терминальный или визуальный ?

Comment: Визуальный.

Comment: @Леха Емельяненко так вроде многооконных редакторов немало...

@ReinRaus vim круче другим -- настроенностью на скорость работы. А "куча текста в режиме редактирования" -- мне понравилось. Ещё в teco была забава -- набрать свою фамилию и посмотреть, что получилось с файлом (какие команды попали в фамилию, и что они сделали)

Comment: >> чем emacs или vim лучше (особенно в наше время)? 
Они хороши тем, что  несмотря на свой возраст, ещё способны вызывать нехилые holywar'ы. Обсуждение любой другой пары редакторов в конечном счете сводиться к обсуждению vim vs emacs. А это обсуждение в свою очередь сводиться к "ваш редактор может только бибикать и портить текст" vs "в вашем редакторе есть все, кроме собственно редактора".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из известных мне редакторов под линукс это умеют делать ещё два - QtCreator и Code::Blocks. Это конечно грубо, назвать IDE редактором, но мы же на форуме программистов, здесь в основном для кода и используются редакторы. Эти два умеют как просто сделать "два (и более) окна просмотра одного файла", так и разделить рабочее пространство для редактирования нескольких файлов.

Также это умеет делать SublimeText (он платный, если что). Но там эта функция немного специфичная. Нужно в меню View->Layout выбрать способ  разделения рабочего пространства, а после этого можно перетаскивать вкладки.

Кстати, IDEA также умеет разделять рабочее пространство (меню Window->Editor Tabs).

> > чем emacs или vim лучше (особенно в наше время)?

Авторы этих редакторов в свое время поняли, что напихать все в один редактор сложно и не нужно и сделали гибкую систему плугинов (хотя это очень спорный вопрос - в эмаксе это своя модификация лиспа, а в виме ещё до недавно свой язык. Сейчас можно на питоне дописывать, но не полностью все). В других редакторах пытаются втиснуть все и сразу.